# custom post type make featured image box full width

Tags: custom-post-types

I want to make `Featured Image` selection box full width.
can anyone help me?

```
function portfolio_post_type() {

$labels = array(
    'name'                  => _x( 'Portfolio', 'Post Type General Name', '33306' ),
    'singular_name'         => _x( 'Portfolio', 'Post Type Singular Name', '33306' ),
    'menu_name'             => __( 'Post Types', '33306' ),
    'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Post Type', '33306' ),
    'archives'              => __( 'Item Archives', '33306' ),
    'attributes'            => __( 'Item Attributes', '33306' ),
    'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Item:', '33306' ),
    'all_items'             => __( 'All Items', '33306' ),
    'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Item', '33306' ),
    'add_new'               => __( 'Add New', '33306' ),
    'new_item'              => __( 'New Item', '33306' ),
    'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Item', '33306' ),
    'update_item'           => __( 'Update Item', '33306' ),
    'view_item'             => __( 'View Item', '33306' ),
    'view_items'            => __( 'View Items', '33306' ),
    'search_items'          => __( 'Search Item', '33306' ),
    'not_found'             => __( 'Not found', '33306' ),
    'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'Not found in Trash', '33306' ),
    'featured_image'        => __( 'Featured Image', '33306' ),
    'set_featured_image'    => __( 'Set featured image', '33306' ),
    'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove featured image', '33306' ),
    'use_featured_image'    => __( 'Use as featured image', '33306' ),
    'insert_into_item'      => __( 'Insert into item', '33306' ),
    'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this item', '33306' ),
    'items_list'            => __( 'Items list', '33306' ),
    'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Items list navigation', '33306' ),
    'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filter items list', '33306' ),
);
$args = array(
    'label'                 => __( 'Portfolio', '33306' ),
    'description'           => __( 'Portfolio post type', '33306' ),
    'labels'                => $labels,
    'supports'              => array('thumbnail'),
    'hierarchical'          => false,
    'public'                => true,
    'show_ui'               => true,
    'show_in_menu'          => true,
    'menu_position'         => 5,
    'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-format-gallery',
    'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
    'can_export'            => true,
    'has_archive'           => true,
    'exclude_from_search'   => false,
    'publicly_queryable'    => true,
    'capability_type'       => 'page',
    'show_in_rest'          => true,

);
register_post_type( 'portfolio_post_type', $args );

}

add_action( 'init', 'portfolio_post_type', 0 );
```

Comment: full width of what? what have you tried?

Comment: You will need to specify what you want to make it full width of. In it's current container on the post edit screen I would consider it already being full width **inside its parent element**, so I am not sure what it is you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to move **Featured Image** meta box to left column. Add this code to your plugin or `functions.php` file of your active theme.

```
add_action( 'do_meta_boxes', 'wpse_269370_move_featured_image_meta_box' );

function wpse_269370_move_featured_image_meta_box() {
    remove_meta_box( 'postimagediv', 'portfolio_post_type', 'side' ); // remove meta box of featured image from current location - 'side'

    add_meta_box( 'postimagediv', __('Featured Image'), 'post_thumbnail_meta_box', 'portfolio_post_type', 'normal', 'high' ); // add meta box of featured image again, at new location - 'normal'
}
```

Comment: it doesn't move the `Featured Image`! I tried to change the box id in `add_meta_box` from `postimagediv` to something else, it worked and moved but doesn't add images as `Featured Image`!

Comment: @amirsa00, it should. please try with a new user account.

Comment: thanks, worked with new user, but why it doesn't work with my account?

Comment: when you rearrange/move metaboxes, WordPress keeps your preference to the database as user meta. this is why new user account works, cause this user doesn't have any preferences stored.